# How do we realistically calculate the monochromatic flux of an object in space?

Tags: visible-light, astrophysics, gauss-law, wavelength, luminosity

1. If the collecting area of a telescope is ∆A, and it collects light for a time interval of ∆t, do we just build a telescope with a very small ∆A and make ∆t and ∆λ very small as well?
   Also, how do we calculate bolometric flux by integrating this formula?
   [image: monochromatic flux formula]
2. For ∆E=nhc/λ, do we substitute λc as shown in the figure, even if the light we collect is over a range of wavelength?
   [image]

Comment: Hmm, I've always thought of telescopes as pretty big devices (e.g., $>\text{m}^2$ areas). But in any event, one would use a band-pass filter to limit the incoming frequencies to be within some $\Delta\lambda$ around a centroid $\lambda_0$ (your frequency of interest).